# Is there a need to change sign for enthalpy value for a reaction that appears in reverse when using Hess's law?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, stoichiometry, enthalpy

#### Problem

> Given the enthalpies of the following reactions
>
> \begin{align}
> \ce{2H(g) &-> H2(g)} &\quad \Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ &= \pu{-437.6 kJ mol^-1} \tag{R1}\\
> \ce{C(s) + 2 H2(g) &-> CH4(g)} &\quad \Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ &= \pu{-75.2 kJ mol^-1} \tag{R2}
> \end{align}
>
> find $\Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ$ of
>
> $$\ce{C(s) + 4 H(g) -> CH4(g)}\tag{R3}$$

#### Answer

> $\Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ = \pu{-950.4 kJ mol^-1}$.

#### Question

Why don't we change the sign of $\pu{-437.6 kJ mol^-1}$ (times two) if we go from $\ce{2 H2}$ to $\ce{4H}?$ Isn't it endothermic when we reverse the reaction $\ce{2H -> H2}$?

Comment: We do, but not in your case, as we are not interested in the reverse reaction..

Comment: There is no point in doing so here, just make sure the expression for the resulting enthalpy holds true algebraically for reactants and products. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Don't use ALL CAPS, it's rude and hearts readability.